# MS-Access: Two tables, one has pre-populated data, one is used for user input

Tags: sql, ms-access, datatable

I might be in over my head here, but as I’m working on my first functional database I had a question about tables and queries:

If I have 2 tables (AUS_Table and UPDMS_Table), and the UPDMS_table has pre-populated data I will import monthly with data of all our employees. The AUS_table data I want the user to input data into based on their specific record. So if Jane Doe selects her name from a drop down, it will populate her information, and then on the following forms she can answer questions which will input data into fields in her record but fields that are on the AUS_Table.

I understand I need to create a query of the two, but not sure where to start so I can see pre-populated info along with a bunch of blank fields to the right of their name.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You need to look at using an append query.

Comment: Does the append option allow to add blank fields next to already created records?

ID-NAME-ADDRESS-INITIAL-SIGN

If the fields above have information in ID, NAME, and ADDRESS, will the new fields INITIAL AND SIGN go next to each record as blank?

Comment: Certainly - if fields are not set as Requried in table design. But why duplicate name and address into AUS - just save ID. And instead of INSERT action SQL, use a form/subform.

Comment: Is employee name unique in UPDMS?

Comment: The employee name is unique, each employee already has a record with their individual information that I will import monthly from another system.

Comment: So employee name is not unique in UPDMS - will be repeated in UPDMS table due to monthly imports? Is there an EmployeeID with each EmployeeName? Is there a DateEntered field? Is there an autonumber ID field so each record has a unique identifier? This unique ID must be passed to related record in AUS. This is what form/subform arrangement is designed to facilitate.